# On Linux Mint, why can't I upgrade the system?

Tags: linux-mint

I have a problem to upgrade Linux Mint Vanessa. It looks like there is some problems with casper. How can I solve the issue?

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  asymptote calibre calibre-bin cjs colord cython3 ecl exfat-fuse fuse fwupd
  gdb gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gnuplot-data gnuplot-qt
  guile-2.2-libs gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse
  gvfs-libs hplip hplip-data jupyter-notebook kaccounts-providers
  kactivities-bin kactivitymanagerd kde-cli-tools kde-cli-tools-data
  kdeconnect keditbookmarks kinit kio kolourpaint kpackagelauncherqml
  kpackagetool5 kpeople-vcard kwayland-data kwayland-integration
  libaccounts-qt5-1 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libapt-pkg-perl
  libautovivification-perl libb-hooks-op-check-perl libcairo-gobject-perl
  libcairo-perl libcjs-dbg libcjs0f libclass-c3-xs-perl
  libclass-xsaccessor-perl libclone-perl libcpanel-json-xs-perl
  libdate-simple-perl libdatetime-perl libdevel-callchecker-perl
  libdevel-caller-perl libdevel-lexalias-perl libdevel-size-perl
  libenchant-2-voikko libencode-eucjpms-perl libencode-hanextra-perl
  libencode-jis2k-perl libencode-perl libextutils-depends-perl libfcgi-perl
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libfuse2 libfwupd2 libfwupdplugin5 libgc-dev libgiac0
  libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib-object-introspection-perl libglib-perl
  libgslcblas0 libhomfly0 libhpmud0 libhtml-parser-perl libio-pty-perl
  libipc-shareable-perl libjuh-java libjurt-java libkf5activities5
  libkf5archive5 libkf5attica5 libkf5auth-data libkf5auth5 libkf5authcore5
  libkf5bluezqt-data libkf5bluezqt6 libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks5
  libkf5calendarevents5 libkf5codecs-data libkf5codecs5 libkf5completion-data
  libkf5completion5 libkf5config-bin libkf5config-data libkf5configcore5
  libkf5configgui5 libkf5configwidgets-data libkf5configwidgets5
  libkf5contacts-data libkf5contacts5 libkf5coreaddons-data libkf5coreaddons5
  libkf5crash5 libkf5dbusaddons-bin libkf5dbusaddons-data libkf5dbusaddons5
  libkf5declarative-data libkf5declarative5 libkf5doctools5
  libkf5globalaccel-bin libkf5globalaccel-data libkf5globalaccel5
  libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5guiaddons5 libkf5i18n-data libkf5i18n5
  libkf5iconthemes-bin libkf5iconthemes-data libkf5iconthemes5 libkf5idletime5
  libkf5itemviews-data libkf5itemviews5 libkf5jobwidgets-data
  libkf5jobwidgets5 libkf5jsapi5 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5
  libkf5kdelibs4support-data libkf5kdelibs4support5 libkf5kdelibs4support5-bin
  libkf5kexiv2-15.0.0 libkf5khtml-bin libkf5khtml-data libkf5khtml5
  libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5 libkf5kiogui5 libkf5kiontlm5
  libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5kirigami2-5 libkf5notifications-data
  libkf5notifications5 libkf5package-data libkf5package5 libkf5parts-data
  libkf5parts-plugins libkf5parts5 libkf5people-data libkf5people5
  libkf5peoplebackend5 libkf5peoplewidgets5 libkf5plasma5 libkf5plasmaquick5
  libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5purpose-bin libkf5purpose5
  libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5sane-data libkf5sane5 libkf5service-bin
  libkf5service-data libkf5service5 libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data
  libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5su-bin
  libkf5su-data libkf5su5 libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5textwidgets5
  libkf5threadweaver5 libkf5wallet-bin libkf5wallet-data libkf5wallet5
  libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5widgetsaddons-data libkf5widgetsaddons5
  libkf5windowsystem-data libkf5windowsystem5 libkf5xmlgui-bin
  libkf5xmlgui-data libkf5xmlgui5 libkwalletbackend5-5 libkworkspace5-5
  libldb2 liblinux-epoll-perl liblist-allutils-perl liblist-moreutils-perl
  liblist-someutils-xs-perl liblocale-gettext-perl libnet-dbus-perl
  libnet-libidn-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnode-dev libokular5core9
  libpadwalker-perl libpango-perl libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl
  libparams-validate-perl libpeas-1.0-0 libperlio-gzip-perl
  libperlio-utf8-strict-perl libphonon4qt5-4 libpolkit-qt5-1-1
  libpoppler-qt5-1 libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libqca-qt5-2
  libqca-qt5-2-plugins libqmobipocket2 libqscintilla2-qt5-15 libqt5core5a
  libqt5dbus5 libqt5designer5 libqt5gui5 libqt5help5 libqt5location5
  libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5positioningquick5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5
  libqt5quick5 libqt5quickcontrols2-5 libqt5quicktemplates2-5
  libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5
  libqt5test5 libqt5texttospeech5 libqt5waylandclient5
  libqt5waylandcompositor5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webengine-data
  libqt5webengine5 libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5webenginewidgets5 libqt5webkit5
  libqt5websockets5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5 libqt5xml5
  libqt5xmlpatterns5 libref-util-xs-perl libreoffice-base
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-help-common libreoffice-help-de
  libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-help-es
  libreoffice-help-fr libreoffice-help-it libreoffice-help-pt
  libreoffice-help-pt-br libreoffice-help-ru libreoffice-help-zh-cn
  libreoffice-help-zh-tw libreoffice-impress libreoffice-java-common
  libreoffice-l10n-de libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za
  libreoffice-l10n-es libreoffice-l10n-fr libreoffice-l10n-it
  libreoffice-l10n-pt libreoffice-l10n-pt-br libreoffice-l10n-ru
  libreoffice-l10n-zh-cn libreoffice-l10n-zh-tw libreoffice-math
  libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer
  librhythmbox-core10 libridl-java libsane libsane-common libsane-hpaio
  libsemanage-common libsereal-decoder-perl libsereal-encoder-perl
  libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libsmbclient libsort-key-perl
  libsub-identify-perl libsub-name-perl libtalloc2 libtdb1 libtevent0
  libtext-bibtex-perl libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-csv-perl
  libtext-csv-xs-perl libtext-iconv-perl libunicode-linebreak-perl
  libunicode-utf8-perl libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libunoil-java libuuid-perl
  libvariable-magic-perl libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvoikko-dev libvoikko1
  libwbclient0 libxml-libxml-perl libxml-libxslt-perl libxml-parser-perl
  libxstring-perl libyaml-libyaml-perl lintian lyx lyx-common maxima-sage
  maxima-sage-share mercurial mercurial-common metacity metacity-common
  node-ajv node-boxen node-cacache node-copy-concurrently node-errno node-gyp
  node-lodash node-mime node-mkdirp node-nopt node-opener node-sshpk node-tar
  node-which node-yargs node-yargs-parser nodejs npm ntfs-3g octave
  octave-common okular okular-extra-backends onboard onboard-common passwd
  perl perl-base perl-openssl-defaults phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-vlc
  plasma-framework printer-driver-hpcups python-nemo python3 python3-apsw
  python3-apt python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-cffi-backend python3-chm
  python3-cups python3-cvxopt python3-cypari2 python3-cysignals-pari
  python3-dbus python3-dev python3-distutils python3-fpylll python3-gdbm
  python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-gmpy2 python3-grpcio
  python3-html5-parser python3-icu python3-jinja2 python3-kiwisolver
  python3-lazy-object-proxy python3-ldb python3-lib2to3 python3-libvoikko
  python3-lxml python3-markupsafe python3-matplotlib python3-minimal
  python3-msgpack python3-netifaces python3-notebook python3-numpy python3-pam
  python3-parted python3-pil python3-ppl python3-protobuf python3-psutil
  python3-pycurl python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia
  python3-pyqt5.qtopengl python3-pyqt5.qtpositioning python3-pyqt5.qtquick
  python3-pyqt5.qtsql python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebchannel
  python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets
  python3-pyqt5.qtxmlpatterns python3-pyrsistent python3-qtpy python3-regex
  python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-samba python3-scipy
  python3-setproctitle python3-simplejson python3-sip python3-spyder
  python3-spyder-kernels python3-stemmer python3-svn python3-systemd
  python3-talloc python3-tdb python3-tk python3-tornado python3-uno
  python3-wrapt python3-yaml python3-zmq python3-zope.interface
  qml-module-org-kde-bluezqt qml-module-org-kde-kconfig
  qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols
  qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons qml-module-org-kde-people
  qml-module-org-kde-purpose qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects
  qml-module-qtqml-models2 qml-module-qtquick-controls
  qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs
  qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets
  qml-module-qtquick-templates2 qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2
  qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts qt5-gtk-platformtheme
  qt5-gtk2-platformtheme qt5-style-plugin-cleanlooks qt5-style-plugin-motif
  qt5-style-plugin-plastique qt5-style-plugins qt5ct qtspeech5-flite-plugin
  qtwayland5 rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugins sagemath sagemath-jupyter
  samba-common samba-common-bin samba-libs sane-utils signon-plugin-oauth2
  singular smbclient sonnet-plugins spyder spyder-common sshfs texinfo
  tmispell-voikko transmission-common transmission-gtk uno-libs-private ure
  vlc vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-skins2
  vlc-plugin-video-output wkhtmltopdf xcas xdg-desktop-portal
  xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xed xed-common xed-dbg xviewer-plugins
The following packages will be upgraded:
  casper
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 521 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/52.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 694577 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../casper_1.470.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking casper (1.470.1) over (1.445.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/casper_1.470.1_amd64.deb 
(--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-premount/20iso_s
can', which is also in package lupin-casper 0.57build1
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/casper_1.470.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Are you running this from a USB installation stick, or is the Casper / lupin component that allows for that installed by default on mint?

Comment: I tried to run the command from the command line, not from a USB stick. Does it really matter if I have the stick plugged on the computer?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that at all.

Comment: "trying to overwrite '/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-premount/20iso_s
can', which is also in package lupin-casper 0.57build1", what happens if you follow this approach: https://askubuntu.com/a/433510/912498 ?

In general try to remove the package and then install it after upgrade.